# Implement every, some in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

So, basically I have a Lisp programming homework. These operations are allowed: quote (’), car, cdr
(cadadr, etc.), first, second (third, etc.), rest, cons, list, append, length, numberp, listp, atom, symbolp,
oddp, evenp, null, not, and, or, cond, equal, defun, let, let*, =, +, -, *, /

But, at some point I needed these operations:
- (every function list)
True if the function is true for every element of list.
- (some function list)
True if the function is true (non-NIL) for some element of list; returns the first non-NIL value.
These functions are in Lisp, but I'm not allowed to use them.

Is there some ways to implement "every" and "some" with the operations above?
EDIT: My guess, it should be something like this:

```
(defun every (fun list)
      (and (fun (car list))
           (every fun (cdr list))))  
(defun some (fun list)
      (or (fun (car list))
           (every fun (cdr list))))
```

Have the "undefined function FUN" error. So the tricky part is running the function FUN.

Comment: It is possible, yes. You're not doing yourself any favors asking for the answer instead of working it out for yourself, however.

Comment: I think you need a `funcall` (to call `fun`) somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure that using funcall is appropiate here, because funcall is a function and it is not included in the list of allowed operations. Make sure that you really need this signatures for solving the problem (every function list) and (some function list). So maybe to solve the problem you need a different aproach, or writing specific functions for each (some #'evenp list) like (some-evenp list). of course the best is the functionational style for reusability, but you are still learning. So try to solve the exercise with your tools and come here with some code you tryed, not general answer